# Sheaves generated by local sections inside a sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $ \mathcal{F }$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on a topological space $ X $. Let $ s_{i} \in  \mathcal{F}  ( U _  { i } )  $ be sections on open sets $ U _{i} $ (which do not necessarily form a cover of $ X  $).  Let $ \mathcal{G} $ be the sheaf generated by these sections i.e. the intersection of all sub-sheaves of $ \mathcal{F }$ that contain these local sections. Is it true that if $ V \subset X $ is open such that $ V  \not \subset \bigcup_{i} U_{i} $, then $ \mathcal{G} ( V) = 0 $?

EDIT: This is false, as shown by the counterexample below (extend the function with compact support in $ (-1,1)$ by zero). However, what is true is the following: if $ V $ does not intersect the union of $ U_{i} $, then $ G(V) $ is $ 0 $ by looking at the stalks of the sub-sheaf given by extension of $ \mathcal{F}$ by zero outside the union of $ U_{i} $.

Comment: This is false : take $\mathcal{F}$ be the sheaf of continuous functions on $X=\mathbb{R}$, $U=(-1,1)$ and $s$ a function with compact support in $U$. Then the subsheaf $\mathcal{G}$ spanned by $s$ satisfies $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{R})\neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your edit. Do you mean the following : if $V\cap \bigcup_i U_i=\emptyset$, then $\mathcal{G}_{|V}=0$ ? Then yes, this is true. In fact $\mathcal{G}=\operatorname{Im}(\bigoplus_i\mathbb{Z}_{U_i}\to\mathcal{F})$.

Comment: Hmmm, just to be sure, $  \mathbb{Z}_{U_{i}} $ is the constant sheaf on $ U_{i} $ extended by zero outside $ U_{i} $, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, because for an open subset $j:U \hookrightarrow X$, we have a natural injection $j_!j^{-1}\mathcal F \hookrightarrow \mathcal F$.

In your case, take $U$ to be the union of the $U_i$. Then $j_!j^{-1}\mathcal F$ contains all $s_i$ and is zero on any open set, that is not contained in $U$ (By the definition of the $j_!$-functor, see Exercise 1.19 in Hartshorne).

Comment: Well, $j_!$ is the *sheaf associated* to $V\mapsto\mathcal{F}(V)$ is $V\subset U$ and $0$ otherwise. So as stated, the statement in the OP is false : take $V$ a disjoint union of $U$ and something else. But it might also be false for connected $V$...